# RubyMine on Windows with rails code on OS X server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubymine

This is a weird question, so bear with me while I try to explain it properly.

I have a Ruby on Rails app running on Heroku, with source code on Git. In my home, I have a Mac small laptop, and a Windows 7 Desktop PC.

What I want is to be able to work the code on RubyMine on my Windows machine. Because of many many shenanigans, working on Windows and then uploading to heroku **just doesn't work.**

Instead, I would like to download my code on my Mac, open it somehow from Windows (on LAN), and be able to run it on the Mac (from RubyMine on Windows), and open it in a browser from Windows.

I've been trying for several weeks now. Have anyone done this before? I know it sounds bizarre, but I really wish to work on my 3 monitors Windows setup.

Comment: _Hint:_ `git` is a distributed version control system.

Comment: @mudasobwa as far as I understand, that doesn't solve the problem, which is running the application in development mode on local machine.

Comment: @MarekLipka maybe you are right; I meant working on windows, then `git` it directly to mac and upload to heroku from there.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is all the incompatibilities on gem versions and other shenanigans that are there in Windows and OS X, it just doesn't work. So I figured it would be easier to just make it work on the Mac, and somehow access it through Windows.

Comment: Maybe try and solve your issues with windows and heroku because I push code from a windows machine to git and deploy to heroku from the same machine all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let RubyMine use an SDK over SSH.

1. go to: *File => Settings*
2. select: *Languages & Frameworks => Ruby SDK and gems*
3. click the *add* icon (plus symbol)
4. choose: *New remote...*
5. select: *SSH Credentials*
6. fill in the host, username, password and path

After adding the remote SDK make sure it is selected as your project SDK.

**edit**

As @GujMil pointed out in the comments below, when running the application the Windows path is send as parameter to the Ruby SDK. After some fiddling I found that you can map the local path to the remote path in the SDK Configuration or Run/Debug Configurations.

1. go back to the SDK configuration (step 1 & 2 previous list)
2. click the *Edit Path Mappings* icon for your remote Ruby SDK ([img](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2017.3/edit_path_mapping_icon.png))
3. add your path maps

For me the following was enough (using Linux instead of OS X):

```
+----------------+-------------+
| Local path     | Remote path |
+----------------+-------------+
| //192.168.0.96 | /home       |
+----------------+-------------+
```

For further info see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html

Comment: This is what I'm currently trying out. I set up a remote Ruby SDK, and then I created a Run configuration with that SDK. When I hit 'Run', the console prints the command:

**/Users/<My_User>/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby Z:/<My_Project>/bin/rails server -b 192.168.1.3 -p 3000 -e development**

Z would be the shared drive on Windows, which links to a folder on the Mac. This is an error because Z:/ doesn't exist on the Mac.

Comment: I found the issue to your problem and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question sounds bizarre, so does my answer. I have experimented a similar setup with Linux servers.

1. Set up a shared folder to host the code on the Mac: [Apple
   instructions here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25346?locale=en_GB)
2. Access the folder over your LAN and edit the code in RubyMine.
3. Open an SSH terminal to your Mac so that you can remotely run the
   Rails server, run necessary commands and view the logs (easy with
   your multi-monitor setup)

Note: RubyMine will likely complain about missing gems.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now, except I use Dropbox instead of shared folders. This works fine. However, what I would like to do is run and execute on the Mac **from RubyMine on Windows.**